# Public, reputable sources of time sync via HTTP to use where NTP is blocked?

Tags: http, time, ntp

Let's say I'm in a corporate network where the NTP protocol is blocked, the BOFH^H^H^H^H sysadmins won't unblock it, and they didn't bother to set up a good internal NTP server. What's a good source that provides time via HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: What OS? Windows has time sync built in

Comment: If you're on a Windows domain, this isn't an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [HTTP Time Protocol / htpdate](http://www.vervest.org/htp/). It's not a *good* source, not compared to NTP.

Other options include [connecting a GPS-receiver](http://www.bytefusion.com/products/ntm/pts/gpstimesynchronization.htm) or using a [dialup modem](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/acts.cfm).

Personally I would complain about the sysadmins to your boss. Correct time is important if you want to accurately judge HTTP cache timeouts and other time-sensitive things

Comment: Not if you're a member of a Windows domain. You have issues with Kerberos if you start playing Goofy. They just need to get off their combined situpons and enable the PDC to get NTP updates..

Answer (score 5):

ANY web server provides the date in the headers of the response, with seconds precision.

You could just access a reputable web site such as https://google.com and trust they keep their clock sane. If you want to be super-sure you can probe multiple sites.

Using https has a benefit over NTP - it is secure!

There is actually a standard in the works for getting time accurately and securely from web servers by using multiple, timed requests: http://phk.freebsd.dk/time/20151129/

Comment: Your last link is dead, but thankfully it is archived: https://web.archive.org/web/2019*/http://phk.freebsd.dk/time/20151129.html (that's the last available date)

Comment: Ahhhh! @MichielB - Updated link: http://phk.freebsd.dk/time/20151129/ - he just reorganized his site, that's all.

Comment: Thanks @JCCyC I've added the updated link in my answer.